Why is there a large difference between measured time and actual time?
I am playing around with big lists to test a RPi cluster.  I am building a list of character strings that I will eventually calculate hashes of to simulate cryptocurrency mining.  The code is running on a Raspberry Pi 3B Rev 1.2.
The code to build the list is:
from pympler import asizeof
import itertools
import time

start = time.process_time()
combos = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement('abcdefghijlkmnopqrstuvwxyz', 6))
stop = time.process_time()
print(len(combos), asizeof.asizeof(combos)/1e6, (stop-start))

The results are:
andrew@master:~ $ python mem_test_1.py 
736281 70.727904 0.68859771

The problem is that the actual time (using a stopwatch) is closer to 45 sec.  This time difference is reproducible when running the code on my M2 macbook (different numbers but still a big discrepancy).  I have also tried time.time() and time.perf_counter() with the same results.
Where is all the missing time going and what have I missed?

Do you have something else putting a heavy load on your system?

No.  The RPi is doing nothing but run this code (it's a 64 bit Raspian OS with no GUI) and the M2 is just doing what it normally does.  The problem is in the that itertools process but I've no idea where or how.

Your program tells me that it took 0.7 seconds, which is nowhere close to the 45 described in your post. Try removing asizeof, etc, and just outputting stop-start, or perhaps run time python main.py in bash

This shouldn't take anywhere near 45 seconds. Something else is taking up all your CPU time.

@user2357112 I agree but the Pi is part of a cluster and does nothing but run these code snippets.  As another test I replaced the combos line with:
combos = ['a' for x in range(736281)]  to get a list of similar size.
Returns 0.2388 sec and actually runs for 5 sec.  That is realistic.

...are you saying you see a discrepancy between 0.2388 seconds and 5 seconds as normal, but a discrepancy between 0.688 and 45 seconds as unrealistic?

Take the asizeof.asizeof(combos) away to see that all the time is spent there ...
